# Check if a combination of cell values already exists on a user input table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

CI have found similar problems to the one I am having but can't quite find the right answer.
I have a C# web form with a table which allows user inputs. The table has 3 columns - ccy1, ccy2 and Rate.

When the user inserts values, they then click a 'save' button which inserts the entered values into an SQL database via an "Insert into table..." statement.

However, I need to produce an error statement when they click the 'save' button if the following is true:
     - the combination of ccy1 and ccy2 already exists in the table

Example table:

**ccy1    ccy2    Rate**

EUR     USD     1.3

GBP     USD     1.7

Now if a user was to try and add a third line where ccy1 = EUR and ccy2 = USD, this should produce an error as this combination already exists (in line 1 of the table).

So I want my C# code to be something like:

```
if (***combination of ccy1 and ccy2 already exists then***)
       { "ERROR MSG" }
       else
       {
       sql += "INSERT INTO table values (ccy1, ccy2, rate)"
       }
```

It is the line marked with stars I can't get my head around after attempting several methods.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

```
        declare @exists bit = 1

        if not Exist(select 1 from Table)
        begin

             @exists = 0

              insert into TABLEX (s, s, s, s, s)
              Values (@ccy1, @ccy2, @rate, etc...)


        end

        select @exists
```

This returns whether or not the file exists, and inserts it if it does not.

In your code, you can check the return value, and then throw an error if it returns a 1.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would do this with a unique constraint on the database table. Then, just try the insert. If your column combination exists, you'll get a constraint violation exception. It's a bit painful working out *which* constraint has been violated (if there's more than one on your table), but possible.

If you need more control, or want to format the exception a bit better, you could do the "if exists (select * from table where col1 = ... and col2 = ...)" test as suggested (but either return a result variable or an output parameter).